# How to Initialize/make changes to database in .NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I've been learning .NET Core for two weeks now and have a bunch of data that should always be in the database from the start.

So following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro#add-code-to-initialize-the-database-with-test-data) I create my database through a class called `DbInitializer.cs` with the function `Initialize(ExamsContext context)` which is called in `Startup.cs`.

Now, this function looks something likes this:

```
public static void Initialize(ExamsContext context)
{
     context.Database.EnsureCreated();

     // Check if it's already populated.
     if (context.Exams.Any())
     {
         return;   // DB has been seeded
     }

     // Add stuff
     var data = new Data { ... };
     context.Data.Add(data);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now this doesn't feel like the "right" way, for instance, every time I wish to change something (like adding stuff to the things that should always be there in the function) I do the dirty fix of adding `context.Database.EnsureDeleted();` at the start.

Now the reason I do it like this is because it's the only way I know how to do it and would love to know a better way but haven't gotten successful in my googling, so I thought I'd ask here for some tips regarding best practices and where I could read more about how this is handled :)

Comment: You could do something similar to Sqlite.. when you add new code, change a "version number" variable.  Check this variable value against a value you store in the database.  If the value is missing, or differs from that in your code, then run some kind of data upgrade procedure.  After upgrade, push the version variable to the database.

Comment: EF Core doesn't seem to support seeding yet (seeding is what you're doing) and you're following the suggested behavior. https://github.com/rowanmiller/UnicornStore/blob/master/UnicornStore/src/UnicornStore/Models/UnicornStore/UnicornStoreExtensions.cs

Comment: you should only have to check whether all the necessary entities are in the DB once at startup and not at each function call. in code make sure they don't get deleted (and don't delete them from the DB directly)

Comment: @woelliJ But if the Initialize-function is called in the `Configure-function` of `Startup.cs`, doesn't that meen that it's only checked once at startup and not at each function call?

Comment: wouldn't it be enough for you to know, that the database has been seeded at startup? you'd only have to make sure nobody can delete the entities you 100% rely on. in EF 5 seeding only happened when creating a database and when a new migration was applied

Comment: Yes it would? In the Configure function of Startup.cs (which, if I understand it right, runs at startup), `DbInitializer.Initialize(context)` is called, which checks "if (context.Exams.Any())` and returns if the database is already seeded (and thus doesn't seed the database).

By the way, looked at the function `context.Model.AddOrUpdate(` which seems to solve the problem of having to clear the database every time I add something to the seeding. (Instead of just using `Add`, which would create duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Someone please add my comment to his question. I lack the reputation for it.
Have you thought about writing an SQL-script? Then you just need a few lines of code and load the content of the sql-file with the functionality needed in it. In that file you can do basic if-statements and check if the database is populated or not.